# how to remove pagelayout while deactivating the feature

Tags: feature

I am facing an issue regarding deactivating a feature which is having some page layouts. I am removing the page layout from the folder.

Here comes the problem, when I am trying to delete a page layout which is used to create a publishing page then I am not able to delete that page layout which is causing showing the page layout into the publishing page creation wizard after deactivating the feature.

Is it possible to do some workaround so that if I deactivate the feature then the page layout also will not display into the creation wizard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide Page Layouts as part of Site Setting > Look and Feel > Page Layouts...

Here is link on how to do it in code...

http://blog.aide-sharepoint.com/index.php/2011/04/cacher-pages-layouts-par-code/

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking to do is hide the page layout do as Chris suggested.

If you want to delete the page layout you will first have to change any page that is currently using that page layout so it uses a different page layout.  As long as a page layout is being used you can not delete it (even if you deactivate a feature that installs it).